# Change the Default TimeOut of AWS Custom Resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Can we change the default timeout of AWS CustomResource, as its default timeout is 1 hour and the job that will return an HTTP response to the custom resource is taking approximately 2 hours to send the response and the custom resource is getting timed out before that.

Comment: You want to change it to a larger value, I'd like to change it to a smaller value.  Certain error types (like a typo in a module name) cause the lambda to fail, but we have to wait 1 hour for the deploy to fail, and another hour for the rollback to complete.   Ouch!

Comment: For this reason, I'll probably cease from invoking lambdas during cloudformation deploy, and instead do my necessary work in scripts that follow the CF deploy.

Comment: Have you tried the technique mentioned in the link here,
https://operatingops.org/2018/10/13/cloudformation-custom-resources-avoiding-the-two-hour-exception-timeout/

Comment: @dghant1024 - OP is not asking about how to handle timeout issues due to error. They are asking because he has a resource that actually takes 2 hours to SUCCESSFULLY complete. It will complete successfully, but after the timeout, at which point CloudFormation assumes it has failed.

Comment: It helps me save an hour by cancelling the update so it then takes one hour for it to rollback. But looking to save that hour too

Answer (score 5):

In November 2019, CloudFormation shifted focus from custom resources to CloudFormation Registry resource providers:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudformation-update-cli-third-party-resource-support-registry/

While there are many other differences between custom resources and Registry resource providers, one is that Registry resource providers
[support `timeoutInMinutes` on `Create`, `Update`, and `Delete` handlers](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-resource-schema#timeoutinminutes), which is [currently configurable from 2 to 2160 minutes (36 hours)](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-resource-schema/blob/f4a2cce3d1c099e6e7586c3ab7f16808c7d9df6b/src/main/resources/schema/provider.definition.schema.v1.json#L21-L23)

---

[Registry resource provider development information can be found here](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-cli/#usage) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation-cli/latest/userguide/index.html) for anyone investigating if this is a suitable alternative

Answer (score -2):

This may be what you are looking for:

https://operatingops.org/2018/10/13/cloudformation-custom-resources-avoiding-the-two-hour-exception-timeout/

Listed above is a good way to check for event errors instead of waiting for the initial default timeout of a cloudformation custom resource,  or waiting an hour for that custom resource to rollback.

Comment: OP is not asking about how to handle timeout issues due to error. They are asking because he has a resource that actually takes 2 hours to SUCCESSFULLY complete. It will complete successfully, but after the timeout, at which point CloudFormation assumes it has failed.

Comment: The link above would have been useful to me, but it's broken.